# Access type information in macro in typed/racket

Tags: reflection, racket, typed-racket

How can I access the types of a structure's members in the `typed/racket` language? The function `extract-struct-info` does give a list of field accessors but not their types.

```
(require (for-syntax racket/struct-info
                     syntax/parse))

(define-syntax (display-struct-info stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(display-struct-info name:id)
     (display (extract-struct-info (syntax-local-value #'name)))
     #'(list)]))

(struct: s ([a : Number] [b : String]))

(display-struct-info s)
```

Outputs:

```
(.#<syntax:12:9 struct:s> .#<syntax make-s> .#<syntax:12:9 s?> (.#<syntax:12:9 s-b> .#<syntax:12:9 s-a>) (#f #f) #t)'()
```

More generally, how can I access typed/racket's types, like getting the list of types in a [union type](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/types.html#%28part._.Union_.Types%29) `(U Number String 'foo 'bar)`, or seeing the arguments to a [polymorphic type](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/types.html#%28part._.Polymorphism%29)?

I am interested only in macro-expansion-time access, *not* run-time access.

Related: [Get the type information in macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429799/get-the-type-information-in-macros) (same question for Common Lisp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From good authority (the developers of Typed Racket) [from the #racket irc channel on freenode]:

```
mithos28: ... the brief answer is that types are not available until after macro expansion
soegaard: Quoting: "I am interested only in macro-expansion-time access, not run-time access."
soegaard: So only after - or also during?
mithos28: only after. #%module-begin from TR does an local expand of the body and then once that returns traverses it and checks types and generates contracts/optimizes
```

Answer (score 1):

A new answer is now possible, but using an alternative to Typed/Racket: the [`turnstile`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/turnstile/index.html) Racket library allows creating typed languages in which the type associated with an expression can be accessed at compile-time.

Unfortunately, I do not know `turnstile` well enough (yet?) to provide a detailed example.